# Ubuntu automatically logs on to guest account

Tags: login-screen, guest-session, auto-login

I installed Zorin 9 using a USB on my Dell Inspiron 1440 laptop

After the installation completed and I rebooted the system, Grub doesn't show up on my external screen, waited for 20 secs, pressed F1 and Fn+F1 both (F1 is the monitor change button in my laptop) and it showed the logon screen for 2 secs and then automatically logs on to guest account. I tried to log out, but again after 2 secs it automatically logs on to the guest account.

Comment: Ask on [unix.se]. Ubuntu is for ubuntu only. Even if it is based on Ubuntu, we only accept those listed here: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Tim is right. This is Ubuntu only.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that there was a linux foru too... Thanks for informing, I will go straight away to the linux foru & post a question there :)

Answer (score 2):

Please type this in the terminal and tell me what you get:-

```
whoami
```

Maybe you can try adding another account by below commands:-

```
sudo useradd newusername
sudo passwd newusername
```

Comment: It is better to ask for additional info in comments. This is not an answer yet.

Comment: I know but I only had 46 reps. As soon as I reach 50, I'll start doing it! :) Anyway, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @SharadGautam You don't have enough rep to comment because you don't have enough to comment. It doesn't mean you can post the comment as an answer.

Comment: Answer updated, please undo -1 @Pilot6

Comment: @SharadGautam I downvoted, not Pilot

Comment: I did not do -1. I did +1 to help you get 50. ;-)

Comment: Ok, updated the answer :)

Comment: how to enter into terminal when I cant login?

Comment: @the_Ma5TeR Go into recovery and then drop to root shell

Comment: But I cant get to see the grub in the external monitor!!

Comment: I am stuck in a really weird situation. OMG.

Comment: Open Grub on Laptop Screen.

Comment: But laptop screen is broken, so I had disconnected it!!

Comment: Haha, Looks like your'e all done. Just imagine the screen in your mind and do it.

Comment: @the_Ma5TeR Thats why I always do a dual boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23839/discussion-between-sharad-gautam-and-the-ma5ter).

Comment: I found out a way to show the grub in the external screen after a lot of searching: boot into livecd, mount into the wubi disk, then mount a few more directories which are required, chroot into the mounted dir (i.e. set the mounted dir as root), then edit the etc/default/grub file using gedit to disable laptop screen and force output through the vga and to change resolution to my monitor's resolution, then save & run the command _sudo update-grub_ and then unmount the drive and voila! So if this happens succesfully, I will run the commands as per your suggesion, and get back to you. :-)